# Problemas al intentar modificar una clase de estilo css

Tags: html, css

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual permite ser adaptativa en los distintos tipos de pantallas pero me estoy encontrando con un "problema", y  es que al momento de querer modificar mi clase css con un media query esta clase no lo hace, y la única forma de poder modificar es agregar al final !important, pero he leído que esto es considerado una mala practica, pero hasta ahora no he podido modificar la clase sin agregar el !important.
Esta es mi clase css:

```
.body-login {
    background-image: url('Content/img/0001.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Y este es el media query con el cual intento modificar la clase css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) {
    .body-login {
        background: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda agregar el codigo necesario para un [mre] !!!

Comment: Además, tu código funciona, asi que el error está en otro lado. - [prueba](https://i.gyazo.com/8eb006a59d8645e997860c9c4607214b.mp4) -

Comment: Prueba del Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/4dn0bg2j/

Comment: a mi tambien me parece extraño, estoy verificando si el problema ocurre porque tengo css en el mismo html y la media query en archivo css, lo hago de esa manera pues asi lo hace asp.net

Comment: @Excorpion pero de antemano gracias por su ejemplo

Comment: solo revisa que el código este así como en el ejemplo, primero tu clase genérica y después tu mediaquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si lo que quieres es que no se vea la imagen en la media query seria asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
    .body-login {
    background-image: url('/icono.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
@media (max-width: 830px) {
    .body-login {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body-login"></div>
</body>
</html>
```